# Move Azure subscription to another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We want to move Azure subscription resources, which are already hosting production system to another Azure AD tenant (using "Change Directory" feature).

I would like to know:

1. If resources will continue to work will this this move is being made?
2. We have locally defined users and groups in tenant from which subscription is moved. Do I understand correctly that these users will need to be recreated?
3. Documentation says that RBAC permissions will be lost. Does this affect only the subscription being moved? Like Owner, Reader, Contributor permissions to subscription?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The move affects rbac roles across all resources in the sub. They refer to user ids that are unique to the tenant so can't be moved.

Comment: Users need to be able to login to the new tenant access the subscription. Whether you create new users for them or add them as guests from another tenant is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. So long as all your resource support being moved then yes they should continue to work.
2. These users will remain in your existing tenant, they will not exist in your new tenant, you will need to create them
3. All RBAC roles on the subscription being moved will need to be recreated. Other subscriptions that are not being moved will not be affected

Comment: 1.  Are there really resources that are not supported? This article does not mention that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory
2. Clear
3. Clear

Comment: No I believe your correct, for a Tennant move you should be good for any resource. There are some restrictions on resources that can be moved between subs.